# Is it possible to add Google AdSense in ebooks?

Tags: ads, adsense, adsense-api

I know that google adsense is available for website but is there any way to add google adsense in ebooks or pdf of a file.Suppose i want to sell an ebooks to peoples and i wanted to put adsense in those ebooks.Is google allowed this kind of thing?

Comment: The ads ara generated dinamically, so if you can have some html in de ebooks and internet access...

Comment: is that legal to used in ebooks?because  google adsense doesn't allowed in email or newsletter.